# Linux kernel panic. Understanding oops message - pgd?

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, panic

I am trying to debug a kernel panic.
kernel log says that

```
[63859.139142] Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address c0a0da06
[63859.139236] pgd = ec040000
[63859.139289] [c0a0da06] *pgd=00a1941e(bad)
```

I am interested in knowing what is pgd?
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pgd` is short for "page global directory", the kernel's name for the top level of a page table.

Comment: Thank you so much. Any idea what does it mean by a bad pgd? Is it a memory corruption? I see that the PC value itself c0a0da06 is not locatable in objdump of vmlinux. In the back trace i see that panic is being triggered by a prefetch abort. Any pointers would be helpful

Comment: @Manty Why are you keeping the back trace a secret?

Comment: `c0a0da06` is not necessarily the PC value, it could also be a virtual address that the code is trying to read or write.  The exact meaning of a bad pgd entry depends on the architecture but usually means that it's marked as not present or not writeable.